# MEF 2 - What is the equivalent of AddExportedValue?

Tags: mef

In MEF, you could specify what instance you wanted to satisfy a Shared export with 'AddExportedValue'.

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
container.AddExportedValue<MyDataSet>(dataset);
```

I can't find the analog in MEF 2.  Could someone please send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent is [`ComposeExportedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986608(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
container.ComposeExportedValue<MyDataSet>(dataset);
```

Comment: Adi, thanks.  For extra credit, is there any chance you know the equivalent in "MEF 2 for Windows Store"?  They appear to have stripped MEF 2 down even further.  The namespace has this concept called 'ConvensionBuilder' which appears to be the equivalent of 'RegistrationBuilder', but I can't find the hooks into it for creating a singleton instance of an object and using it as the Exported value.